# Connecting NTC Thermistor to Breadboard

Tags: microcontroller, connector, thermistor

## Background:

I've inherited a project that uses multiple [100KOHM NTC Thermistors](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/temperature-sensors-ntc-thermistors/508?k=615-1006-ND) connected to a microcontroller box via [Thermistor Extension Wire](https://www.omega.com/googlebase/product.html?pn=EXTT-3CU-26S-100&gclid=CjwKCAjwu7LOBRBZEiwAQtfbGAzpgBIglbZCeD8tlzCepQR7tE3qNUodT1mWXPrm9YXQQwzuCRWmcxoClWgQAvD_BwE).

---

## Problem:

- The [3 pin connector](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/3M/37103-B163-00E-MB/?qs=%2fha2pyFadujXycWWEorS7l1pgzjbYZxL2C%2foK7UlRclE6OKVg6oQ%2fg%3d%3d) and its [socket with latch](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/3M/37303-B163-0PE-MB/?qs=%2fha2pyFaduh7Q6veTOXLPxzC84zXX7GnZhUniWKg8aL2IlkZ9Dk%2fvw%3d%3d) that was being used previously is now effectively out of stock (as only I need about 200).
- I haven't sourced many connectors of this type before so my vocabulary in the subject area is limited *(and consists primarily of the word "thing.")*.

---

## Question:

I need to find a new connector that will connect the thermistor to my microcontroller without compromising my measurement. What type of connector would be best suited given the following design requirements:

- The new connector needs to be readily available in smaller quantities (preferably some standard sold by multiple vendors)
- The new connector's socket needs be attached to my microcontroller case to act as a pass-through between the microcontroller and the outside world (ambient temperature)

If anyone has a recommendation as to what I should look for in a new connector (or what I should avoid) I'd greatly appreciate the input.

Comment: Shopping is off-topic.

Comment: Oh, sorry. is there a better place to ask this?

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic on all SE sites, try and pose it as an electronic design question

Comment: Edited: is this any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temperature signals are usually slow, so the usual parameters for connectors, e.g. rated impedance are not an issue. This is a very forgiving application. My recommendation will be anything with:

1. A mechanical latch, or maybe screwed in. There might be a reason why they selected one with this before. Might there be a chance for the thermistor to be accidentally disconnected?
2. Plated contacts. Oxidation of your contacts will seriously disrupt your measurement quality. Go for Gold?